# Updating Array comparison function for strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, compare

I'm working with pre-written code for a quiz trivia game, and I have to update the games question choices from number values to strings. But I don't exactly know what to change in the code for the user choice to be compared to the correct answer. Currently, for number answers, the code compares the array placement of the correct choice in the choices array, with a correctAnswer variable. My best guess would be that the change has to occur in the displayScore function shown at the bottom.

A current question object:

```
        {
            question: "What is 2*5?",
            choices: [2, 5, 10, 15, 20],
            correctAnswer: 2
        }
```

And the updated question object will be:

```
        {
             question: "Which list contains words that are NOT names of shoe types:"
             choices:[   "A. Oxford, jelly, boat, clogs, stiletto, mary jane",
                         "B. Loafer, gladiator, wedge, mule, platform",
                         "C. Pump, moccasin, wingtip, sneaker, derby, monk",
                         "D. Chalupa, dogler, hamster, croonley, frankfurt"],
             correctAnswer : "D. Chalupa, dogler, hamster, croonley, frankfurt"
        }
```

Currently the parts of the code for computing the correct answer are:

```
//Array containing user choices
var selections = []; 

// Reads the user selection and pushes the value to an array
  function choose() {
    selections[questionCounter] = +$('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
  }

// Computes score and returns a paragraph element to be displayed
  function displayScore() {
    var score = $('<p>',{id: 'question'});

    var numCorrect = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
      if (selections[i] === questions[i].correctAnswer) {
        numCorrect++;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: `correctAnswer` refers to the key in `choices`. Quite frankly, I think the original way of handling the correct answers is a lot more versatile.

Comment: Make choices an array of objects. Then you can split the key/description, eg. `[{ 'A', 'Oxford, jelly, boat, clogs, stiletto, mary jane' },{ 'B', ... }]`. Then you can simply check the answer against the correct key

Comment: Why don't you simply keep the `correctAnswer` be an index (in your example: `3`)? It'll work for an array of strings as well as it does for an array of numbers.

Comment: Simply remove the + ...

Answer (score 0):

#### Credits:

As mentioned by [Jonas w](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5260024/jonas-w) in the comments, the problem is the `+` before the `$().val()`. Because it didn't get any upvotes nor explanation, I thought I'd elaborate:

#### The *bug*

When retrieving a value from an input, the value is always a `string`. The correct answer in your initial example is a `number`. Because you compare using `===`, the two are not equal: `2 === "2"` returns `false`.

Adding a `+` operator is a short way of "casting" a value to a number. (Opinion:) Many people dislike it because it can be easy to miss and hard to interpret for beginners. A perhaps clearer way would be to write `Number(x)` or use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`.

The problem is, that once your required value is a `string`, the `+` operator will try to make a number from a non-numeric-like string. The outcome will be, quite well named, `NaN`, which stands for *Not a Number* and can be checked for using `isNaN`

**I.e.:**
Works:

```
const required = 2;
const input = "2";
required === +input; // 2 === 2 -> true
```

Breaks:

```
const required = "Hello world";
const input = "Hello world";
required === +input; // "Hello world" === NaN -> false
```

#### How to fix it

Concluding: removing the `+` will *fix* the string based answers, but *break* the number based answers.

My advice would be to *remove* the `+`, but make sure your answer arrays contain strings. (For example, by mapping using `[2, 3, 4].map(String)` or `toString`)

Other possible fixes include:

- Using the `==` operator inside `displayScore` to compare the user input to the required value (**not** recommended)
- Adding a `switch` statement for the type of the array's value to pick custom comparison methods for `number`, `string` and perhaps other values.
- Using the `index` in the array instead of the value, as suggested by user [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) (Might make the `question` object a bit harder to read, though)

#### Examples

Some examples that can help you get a feel for the differences between values:

```js
var val = $("input").val();

console.log("typeof val ->", typeof val);
console.log("typeof 2 ->", typeof 2);
console.log("val == 2 ->", val == 2);
console.log("val === 2 ->", val === 2);
console.log("+val === 2 ->", +val === 2);
console.log("Number('2') === 2 ->", Number(val) === 2);

var nonNumericString = "Hello world";
console.log("+'Hello world' ->", +nonNumericString);

var answers = [2, 3, 4];
console.log("'2' in [2, 3, 4] ->", answers.includes(val));
console.log("'2' in [2, 3, 4].map(String) ->", answers.map(String).includes(val));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input value="2">
```